# button visibility in openerp

Tags: python, odoo

I am using openerp 5.16 web.

Is there any way we can hide button depending upon the logged in user.

or how can i control the group visibility depending upon the user group.

Answer (score 1):

- Depending the logged in user : 
  You can use the variable 'uid' but I don't think you can do 'uid.name' or 'uid.groups_id'. So the easier method will be the second.
- Depending on the groups
  Example : We have some users who are managers and others not, create a group 'Manager' (in a xml file !!!) and add this group to managers. Now change the field in the xml like this :

  `<field name="name" string="this is the string" groups="my_module.my_reference_to_the_group"/>`

The field will only be visible for managers

Answer (score 1):

Setting visibility based on user group is the way to do that. Add a `groups` attribute to whatever controls you want to hide. A good example is the [Extra Info tab](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-addons/5.0/view/2935/sale/sale_view.xml#L157) of the sales order screen. It's only visible if the user is a member of the Extended UI group.

```
<page groups="base.group_extended" string="Extra Info">
    <field name="th_weight"/>
    <field name="address_allotment_id" select="2"/>
    <separator colspan="4" string="Properties"/>
    <field colspan="4" name="property_ids" nolabel="1"/>
</page>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a New Group, say "Button Visible".

Then Add users in this group to whom you want to Display Button.

Then Add this Group on Button like this:

```
<button name="xyz" groups="Button Visible" .../>
```

Answer (score 0):

In OpenERP Groups are Higher Level Security on View Elements on almost all view element in XML you will find groups attribute, So you use Group attributes for the same.
e.g. If in your Module if you are defining some Group/s so you can advantage of group attribute of the tag button on view like

```
<button name="name" type="object|workflow|action" string="" groups="<your_group_external_id>,<module.group_external_id>" />
```

Where external_id stands for the Unique XML defined on record tag. So now Only User blog ot receptive assigned groups can only see button in view.

Regards